# Eigenvalues of composite operators

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\SEnd}{End}$Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over some algebraically complete field $F$. Let $\Phi,\Psi \in \SEnd[X]$ be endomorphisms on $X$. Define the operator $L \in \SEnd[\SEnd[X]]$ by
$$L(T) := \Phi T - T \Psi
$$
What are the eigenvalues of $L$?

If $(\lambda,u)$ and $(\nu,v)$ are eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs for $\Phi,\Psi^\intercal$, then we can define $T := uv^\intercal$ (where $u,v$ are viewed as vectors in $F^n$). Then
$$\begin{align*}
L(uv^\intercal)
&= \Phi uv^\intercal - uv^\intercal \Psi \\
&= \lambda uv^\intercal - u(\Psi^\intercal v)^\intercal \\
&= \lambda uv^\intercal - u(\mu v)^\intercal \\
&= (\lambda - \mu) uv^\intercal
\end{align*}$$
Since $\lambda - \mu$ where $\lambda,\mu$ ranges over the eigenvalues of $\Phi,\Psi$ have the potential to take $n^2$ different values, I suspect that all eigenvalues of $L$ can be written in this form. Is this true?

Addendum: The answer seems to be affirmative using minimal polynomials. If no one answers I will fill in an answer soon.

Comment: You're right: all eigenvalues of $L$ can be written in this form

Comment: One approach is to note that $L$ can be identified with $L = I \otimes \Phi - \Psi \otimes I$ via [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))